# installed application keeps open port

Tags: iptables, ip, netstat

I installed an application (a text editor) and it keeps a connection alive. I *blocked the IP with `iptables`*, but the port stays open.

`netstat` shows:

`tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1:<port>  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2538/<application>`

1. why they maintain a port/IP open in my PC?
2. I guess maybe there's something related with updates, but is it risky?
3. how can I close the port?

Comment: Try `kill -9 2538`

Comment: But that will kill the process. I still want to use the application.

Comment: Can you paste `iptables` rules that you have used?

Comment: I dropped the *suspicious* IP `iptables -A INPUT -s <IP> -j DROP`

Comment: I thought this could block the port but was not successful: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port <port> -j DROP`

Comment: 1) Without you revealing what software application you are using, we're reduced to guess work as to why it opens a listening port. 2) Is it? Without knowing the application it's guess work. 3) you cannot "close" the port, the application bind()'s to it and LISTENs for traffic. The best you can do is block traffic to that port. Note, however, that is only listening on loopback (127.0.0.1) and therefore not reachable via an external interface.

Comment: Thanks @DravSloan ! the application is called **haroopad** used for writing markdown files. Your **Note** seems to solve my doubt. However, why and application, like this markdown editor, would like to have such access opened? How risky it is?

Comment: Having a brief look at the source code (https://github.com/rhiokim/haroopad), it has an "app" and a "viewer", which communicate via this port. I would assume to allow asynchronous operation on the "viewer" frontend. If you want to dig deeper, the code base is there to view at the author's github.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth column states that the program is listening only for connections on the network interface whose IP address is [127.0.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). That means that it's only listening on the [loopback interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), so it can only receive connections from the same machine that it's running on, not from other machines connected over the network.

The application presumably has some kind of client-server mode that allows commands to be sent to a running process. TCP is one of the ways to do it.

I hope you didn't block the IP address 127.0.0.1 with iptables, as that is likely to disrupt a lot of things. If you blocked the port used by the program, don't — if it opens the port, it's presumably for a reason.

In any case, blocking traffic with iptables won't close a port. Iptables prevents packets from reaching their destination. It doesn't change anything about whether someone is listening at the destination. You'll still see the port open in `netstat` as long as the process is listening.